# 1995 VW golf Mk3. need to know where to find camshaft position (hall) sensor

Tags: vw, golf, sensor

I have a 95 VW Golf Mk3 and it has been running badly. I first thought it was bad gas because of how it drove. Now it keeps driving like that but worse. It stutters when trying to pick up speed at stop lights it die. I finally got 3 codes off it 00515, 00553, 00513. These codes are directly related to the camshaft position sensor. Where is it located? I cannot find it!

Answer (score 3):

If your engine is the ABA engine, it's located in the distributor. You have to disassemble the distributor in order to get it out. For the money, they suggest it's a good time to [replace the entire distributor](http://www.germanautoparts.com/Volkswagen/Golf/EngineElectrical/45/2). (NOTE: I'm not promoting that site ... please do your research and get what is right for you. Please notice what is said on the line for the sensor, though.)